# WordPress pagination throws 404 on page 2 and up

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a site with several custom post types and of course a search for everything.

Now when I type in `/?s=new` I get a results and I can see pagination telling me that there are 9 pages, but when I press any of pagination links I get URL like this `/page/2/?s=new` that gives me 404.

Any idea why?

Also should mention that I have same pagination at blog pages and it works with no issues. This is only on search results page

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like its an issue with your routing parameter.
Perhaps there is conflicting page names when it is generating a slug, or there is no default holder for the page number

checkout this article
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-for-custom-post-types?replies=40#post-1620826
has solutions to what I'm talking about

cheers